# query on Set<> with HQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i have my mapped classes like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact", catalog = "pagesjaunes")
public class Contact implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<Phone>(0);

    [...]

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "telephone", catalog = "pagesjaunes")
public class Phone implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Contact contact;
    private String phoneNumber;

    [...]
}
```

Can I make a query like that on `Contact` with `HQL`:

`from Contact where phones.phoneNumber = 06487954`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the syntax is incorrect. `phones` is a path to a Set, and Set doesn't have a phoneNumber attribute. You need a join to do what you want:

```
select c from Contact c
inner join c.phones [as] phone
where phone.phineNumber = '06487954'
```

This is of course explained in [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins).

Note: `[as]` means that you can use `as` or omit it.